# Ubuntu 18.04 server lost network access after moving

Tags: networking, 18.04, server, dns

I recently moved, so I had to shutdown my (18.04, updated from 16.04) server. Everything worked fine before moving, but since moving and setting up the network again, the main OS cannot update, "apt upgrade", ping external networks or download.

Only one action has worked so far: `route add default gw 192.168.0.1 p3p1`

What is stranger, is the 3 guest OS I run from that host work perfectly:

- a pfSense VM with a vtd passthrough to a dual gigabit network card, acting as the networks internet router/firewall
- a Debian guest running low spec Debian, hosting PiHole and macvtap for its networking
- a third guest running Lubuntu that has VTd access to a single Gigabit card.

The main system (with its own dedicated NIC), pihole (macvtap), and Lubuntu (vtd card), run into an old router set in switch mode with only its access point being active. The rest of the network operates perfectly (3 Android phones, 2 windows PCs and an Xbox One).

The /etc/network/interfaces file has no reference to p3p1 ; /etc/network/interfaces.d and /etc/netplan contain nothing at all.

I can ssh into the server from within the network and samba shares still work, as are nfs shares between the main host and the Lubuntu guest.

Aside from having to remount the nfs shares in Lubuntu after the guests have fully booted, this setup has worked fine for months. This setup has ballooned from a basic single OS system to the setup described over years.

Following best practices, what's a reliable troubleshooting plan of action?

EDIT 1:
as requested, the output of `ip a` is as follows:

`ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: p3p1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether d0:50:99:9b:bb:2f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.0.139/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global dynamic p3p1
       valid_lft 6465sec preferred_lft 6465sec
8: macvtap0@p3p1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 500
    link/ether 52:54:00:91:11:62 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 169.254.23.72/16 brd 169.254.255.255 scope global macvtap0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::711b:c0b9:3b0:b333/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever`

the output from the command `nmcli con show` shows that p3p1 is present and active

`ethernet  ********-****-****-****-************  ethernet  p3p1
macvtap0  ********-****-****-****-************  macvlan   macvtap0`

as an additional note, the system started on 16.04, and has been through at least one upgrade, as such i am unaware which network manager it is   using.

Comment: What is the output of `ip a`?

Comment: i added the output of `ip a` to my original post since the comments are too size limiting.

Comment: I'd recommend attempting to manually add the connection via `nmcli`. 
https://www.tecmint.com/configure-network-connections-using-nmcli-tool-in-linux/
Then you can decide whether to use netplan or install legacy `ifupdown`(if you don't have it already)  package to configure via /etc/network/interfaces. The fact configuration files are missing both places is a good callout.

Comment: apologies, i thought i had already posted a reply, and we've been somewhat busy.

apparently `ifupdown` is installed, and nmcli has a configuration in place for p3p1.

Comment: i am still having to use the `route add default gw 192.168.0.1 p3p1`

this setup used to work perfectly at our old house, with the same isp, and the same configuration, so i am at a loss as to what is actually wrong.